# Very weird network latency

Tags: networking, ssh

I have an Ubuntu machine that I ssh into that displayed some weird behavior. I noticed some lag in my ssh session so I pinged it from my laptop. It averaged about 2000-3000 ms ping time. Then, in the ssh session, I ran `watch -n 0.2` program (at first I ran it with `iptables -v -L` and later ran it with `echo hello`). While `watch` was running ping time dropped SIGNIFICANTLY (averaging around 50-100 ms). As soon as I kill the `watch` program ping times went back up.

Does anyone know why this behavior might be happening and/or how to make the lag go away permanently?